# communication between two multiprocessing in real time

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 2 processing, I need that when something happened on one process, something else will happen on the other.
For example:

```
import multiprocessing


def function_1(num):
    while True:
        status = False
        for i in range (num):
            if i == 100:
                status = True
            i +=1


def function_2():
    while True:
        if status == True:
            print("status changed")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 101
    a = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_1,args=(num,))
    b = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_2)


    a.start()
    b.start()


    a.join()
    b.join()
```

This code obviously does not work, how can I make it work? I don't need one process to end and then get the result, I need the process to continue after that... is there a way to do that?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a using a shared variable, for the purpose of making `function_2` wait until `function_1` reaches a certain state, you can create a `multiprocessing.Queue` instance to pass to both functions, and take advantage of the fact that `Queue.get` blocks until the queue receives something to dequeue, and make `function_1` put something into the queue once it reaches the desired state:

```
import multiprocessing

def function_1(queue, num):
    while True:
        for i in range(num):
            print(i)
            if i == 3:
                queue.put(None)

def function_2(queue):
    queue.get()
    print('do something')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = 5
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    a = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_1, args=(queue, num))
    b = multiprocessing.Process(target=function_2, args=(queue,))
    a.start()
    b.start()
```

Comment: thank you :) I write queue.put("something")  in function_1, and in function_2 I did:  while True: if  not queue.empty: print ("do something")
but unfortunately, it does not work :\ you have an idea why?

Comment: You should call the `empty` method by adding parentheses after the function name: `queue.empty()`. Note that constantly checking if the queue is empty in an infinite `while` loop will unnecessarily cost a lot of CPU time. You should stick to `queue.get()` as demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: But I need is to constantly check if the status change, when the status changes it will cause something, queue.get() check only one time...

Comment: I see. If you status can flip back and forth you can indeed make `function_2` call the `empty` method in a loop indeed, and make `function_1` call `queue.get` once it needs to pause `function_2`.

Comment: Thank you, just so I will know, there is other way? because as you mention, it will take a lot of CPU time...

Comment: You're welcome. If the infinite loop does nothing other than checking for the queue's emptiness then it'll take a lot of CPU time, but it also does something else in the same loop that involves I/O, then the overhead of checking for the queue's emptiness will be minimal compared to the I/O time. Unless the "something else" you do is also purely computational you shouldn't be too worried. Check the CPU usage of the process if you are.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, if I will add the line "time.sleep(6) for example, so it will check only 10 times in minutes, that could help right?

Comment: Yep `sleep` will definitely solve the CPU usage issue as long as a few seconds of delay is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `.join()` after the `start()`.
Try this :

```
a.start()
b.start()

a.join()
b.join()
```